# A case with no chance of being solved

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

It seems to me that the police have a special name for criminal cases, which will in all probability remain unsolved. Is it 'cold case'?

Comment: A "cold case" is simply an investigation that the police authorities have suspended indefinitely without achieving a satisfactory resolution; I suspect that the term arose in connection with the hunting idiom "the trail has gone cold." You might expect that a case with no chance of being solved might be called something like "an absolute zero case"—but it's not.

Comment: "unsolved crime" is a very common phrase for old cases that have remained unsolved and attract a lot of dubious theories but little evidence (e.g. Jack the Ripper); I'm not aware of anything more specific but perhaps there are slang terms used by law enforcement officers that aren't more widely known.

Answer (score 2):

***[Perfect crime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_crime)*** conveys the idea:

> - Perfect crime is a colloquial term used in law and fiction (especially crime fiction) to characterize ***crimes that are undetected, unattributed to a perpetrator, or else unsolved*** as a kind of technical achievement on the part of the perpetrator.

(Wikipedia)

Comment: It is perfect for its perpetrator - yet I meant the police, it gives them headache, boss nagging, lost faith in their capabilities. So they sure have to have a derogatory name for such cases